# Query Builder KQL return only items/folders at top level

Tags: 2013, search, cswp, kql

I'm using content search webparts with cross-site publishing in an on-prem SP2013 site. I've got a result source that is limited to a specific library using Query text:

```
{searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) SPSiteUrl:https://sites.sp.kp.org/teams/lscsp-cat10 ListId:0cd3f39e-61e4-456e-a149-85cb79292589
```

That retrieves all items from the list -- which includes individual documents, folders, and document sets. I want to only retrieve items at the first level of the library. Only documents and folders at the top level, not documents inside folders or document sets.

I've been looking through [these tutorials](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/03/sharepoint-search-queries-explained.html) on KQL and find lots of ways to limit to the parent of a term set.

I did find the managed property **ParentLink** and am using something like this:

```
ParentLink:'https://<site>/<library name>/Forms/AllItems.aspx'
```

Which does work because the parent link for anything in a folder will be different. But that seems pretty much like a bad hack.

Is there an official way using KQL to tell a CSWP "Only contents of this folder, don't look in nested folders."?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `ParentLink: {/yourlibname/}`